# Can i view word document in siverlight?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, ms-word

If someone can help me with a silverlight tool or any kind of tool in which I can display word document in a webpage. Not in iframe or anything like that but in a tool.

Comment: if you really are in such rush, try out the out of the box solution of DevExpress Rich Text Editor: http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/Silverlight/Rich_Editor/

should allow you loading Word Documents and even allow to edit them and save back...

Comment: Sorry about the urgent at the end of the question..just in desperate need of it ..almost spent an age.. :)

Comment: check here for a full demo: http://demos.devexpress.com/DemoCenter/Silverlight/?RichEditDemo#Load/Save_DOC

Comment: In case you use Silverlight 5 and your application runs out-of-browser, you get direct access to word.

Comment: @DavidePiras dude the editor costs a fortune !! isnt there somethng cheaper ..i just want to display it..not edited it ect ect !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extend this Silverlight 2.0 control to a more current version and view Word documents (2007 and later): [TextGlow](http://textglow.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

In case you use Silverlight 5 and your application runs out-of-browser, you get direct access to word.

What you can do as well is create a seperate .aspx page that returns the requested document and call that page. Maybe you could use the browser control for this, but the one in Silverlight works out-of-browser only, if I remember correctly.

Word has to be installed on the client.